# Fullcalendar does not refresh events from XML file

Tags: fullcalendar

Why full calendar does not refresh events from XML file. I add one item to XML file and the fullcalendar does not refresh. Any idea?
Its asp.net and mysql and when I insert one item on my XML file I need to refresh

Here is my code:
There are 2 files asp.net and C#
If I refresh the webpage it seems to work

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="calendario.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>            
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>          
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
                   //lang: 'pt',
                   header: {
                       left: 'prev,next,today',
                       center: 'title',
                       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                   },
                   eventLimit: true,
                   businessHours: true,
                   editable: true,   
                   events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                       $.ajax({
                           url: 'eventos_professor.xml',
                           dataType: 'xml',
                           data: {
                               // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                               start: start.unix(),
                               end: end.unix()
                           },
                           success: function (doc) {                                
                               var events = [];                              
                               $(doc).find('event').each(function () {
                                   events.push({
                                       title: $(this).attr('title'),
                                       start: $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed
                                       end: $(this).attr('end'), // will be parsed
                                       textColor: "red",
                                       backgroundColor: "black"
                                   });

                               });
                               callback(events);                               
                           }
                       });
                   },                   
                   selectable: true,
                   dayClick: function (fecha, evento, vista) {
                       //alert(fecha.format());                      
                       $("#myModal").modal();                       
                   }                    
               });
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

           });
       </script>

</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div class="container">
          <div id="calendar">

          </div>
      </div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Marcar aula</h4>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtData">Data:</label>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtData"  runat="server" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>                  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row" style="background-color:darkgray;">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="DropDownList1">Escolha a Turma:</label>                  

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtHorainicio">Hora início:</label>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtHorainicio" type="Time" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="txtHorafim">Hora fim:</label>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtHorafim" type="Time" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </div>
              </div>
             <div class="col-xs-4">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="CheckBox1">Repetir Evento</label>

                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                         <ContentTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"  Checked="false" />
                         </ContentTemplate>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
                 </div>

             </div>
          </div>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div id="opcoes" runat="server" visible="false">
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" Text="Registar em Férias" runat="server" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" Text="Registar em feriados" runat="server" />
                          </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <label for="txtDataLimite">Até à data:</label>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDataLimite" Text="2018-12-31" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">                  
                  <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server" Text="Close" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                  <asp:Button ID="Button2" class="btn btn-default btn-success"  runat="server" Text="Gravar" OnClick="Add_XML" />

              </div>

              </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
       </form>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
and C# code:
     protected void Add_XML(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XElement xml = XElement.Load("mypath\\eventos_professor.xml");
        xml.Add(new XElement("event",
        new XAttribute("title", "Agora sim"),
        new XAttribute("start", "2018-07-23 19:45:00"),
        new XAttribute("end", "2018-07-23 21:45:00")));
        xml.Save("mypath\\eventos_professor.xml");




    }
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Is something caching the XML file (server or browser)? Check your network tools in the browser to see if your new event is contained in the XML which is coming as the response of the ajax call. Is your XML event valid (e.g. containing valid start/end times)? You didn't show us a sample of the file or the specific XML snippet. Do you have any errors in your browser console? Is the event at a time which is within the current display of the calendar? None of this we know, only you can investigate and share the results with us.

Comment: Actually, as well, you say you add something to the XML file...but how is fullCalendar supposed to know that? It only goes looking for new events when you tell it to - you have to move from one month to the next, or specifically run "refetchEvents". The XML is on the server. The code running in the browser has no way to know if the server data has been updated unless it makes a request to the server. So maybe if you want it to refresh automatically you need to run "refetchEvents" at regular intervals.

Comment: ADysin you're right. If I write Response.AppendHeader("refresh", "5"); the page refresh and works. Need to do only one time otherwhise I can't do anything on the page. It works on Firefox not in Chrome, why?

Comment: solved. I have to refresh the ajax cache. Now it works